# How can I get European countries list in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have a custom checkout page for samples, Where I want to get list of European countries list in magento 2.

Comment: Please state more about what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, accept @GielBerkers answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option called 'European Union Countries' (`general/countries/eu_countries`). You can use this configuration setting to get the list of all these countries. By default, all EU-countries are selected.

Example from within a helper:

```
$countries = $this
    ->scopeConfig
    ->getValue(
        'general/country/eu_countries'
    );
var_dump($countries);
```

Outputs:

```
string(83) "AT,BE,BG,CY,CZ,DK,EE,FI,FR,DE,GR,HR,HU,IE,IT,LV,LT,LU,MT,NL,PL,PT,RO,SK,SI,ES,SE,GB"
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please update your question and share with us the code you've tried

Comment: My bad, it needed to be `country`, not `countries`.

Answer (score 0):

Like above

```
$countries = $this
->scopeConfig
->getValue(
    'general/country/eu_countries'
);
var_dump($countries);
```

but remember to create scopeConfig in your constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ...
}
```

then information about EU countries from **Stores->Configuration->General->General->Country Options->European Union Countries** will be load into $countries variable, so if You don't set this field in admin, no information will be loaded.