# Get list of EU countries in JS file in checkout

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to get a list of the EU countries in my checkout (the list that is available in the backend).

I found [this PHP code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153928/how-can-i-get-european-countries-list-in-magento-2) to get the list but i'm not sure on how I would get it into the JS my checkout. I need to show a field depending on if the selected country is in Europe.

Thanks in advance.

I currently have this:

```
   <item name="vat-country-code" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">                                                 
              BB_Checkout/js/view/vat-country-code
           </item>
   </item>
```

But of course this leads to a JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I added the following PHP file to my module:

Vendor/Module/Block/EuCountries.php

```
<?php
 namespace BB\Checkout\Block;

 use Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory as CountryCollectionFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

 class EuCountries extends Template
 {
protected $_countryCollectionFactory;
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    CountryCollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
    Template\Context $context,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getEuCountries()
{
    $euCountries = $this
        ->scopeConfig
        ->getValue(
            'general/country/eu_countries'
        );

    return $euCountries;
}
```

}

And the corresponding phtml file:

```
<script>
 window.euCountries = "<?php echo $block->getEuCountries(); ?>".split(',');
</script>
```

And I added a new referenceContainer to checkout_index_index.xml under body.

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="BB\Checkout\Block\EuCountries" template="BB_Checkout::eu-countries.phtml" name="eu-countries" />
 </referenceContainer>
```